# Python path configuration for pyinstaller

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pyinstaller

I am having issues with getting pyinstaller version 3.6 to work to make my application executable. The crux of my problem is that pyinstaller is not compatible with python 3.8, but when I check python --version on my terminal it confirms I have python 3.7. However, when I check my pip path it gives me `pip 20.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`. Also, I am currently using VScode as my editor, and when I check `sys.version_info` in my app script it gives me version 3.8 as well. I tried creating a virtual environment in new file, double checking the package.json with 3.7, but when I run sys.version_info it still gives me 3.8 (I am still a beginner at using shell/terminal so I am confused as to why since my python version is 3.7 on my shell).

I worried about doing a complete uninstall of python and pip since I've read it could mess up the paths and cause complications repairing. How can I change the pip path to python 3.7 or have my script run 3.7 so that I can use pyinstaller on my macOS?

Comment: Although it says 3.7 when i check python version on terminal. When I do `import site; site.getsitepackages()` in python shell i get the same 3.8 path that shows when I check pip. It seems like the paths are correct.

Comment: what does `python3 --version` show you

Comment: python3 --version was showing me 3.7.7. However, I did end up just reinstalling python 3.7 and pip and deleting python 3.8 from /Library/Frameworks. So the versions are now correct. But my issue with pyinstaller remains, as my app opens for a few seconds and then immediately closes.

Comment: So it builds OK with pyinstaller? Are there any error outputs when it crashes?

Comment: Correct, pyinstaller correctly builds the files and puts them into a dist folder, which contains the app and unix executable file. Clicking the app file results in nothing, no errors. Clicking the unix executable file works, but the app is opened with a terminal window alongside.

Comment: When I took a deeper look into the app file I find 4 folders Frameworks, Info.plist, MacOS, Resources. However, the Frameworks folder is empty I am wondering if that is the issue.

Comment: Problem solved using py2app, I have forsaken pyinstaller.

Comment: Glad you figures it out